# Kendo-UI Edit template not working with Vue Template Single File Component

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, vue-component, kendo-ui-grid

I am using kendoui grid vue wrapper, I find out at kendoui vue documentation that I can use a single file Component for kendo templates, I am working on a editable grid with a popup editor, what I am doing is setting the property "editable" with the name of the method that return the template and template args, the same thing as the documentation of Vue Templates of KendoUi, but It just ignore the function and get inline editable.

The other way that I tried is to set the editable property like "{mode: 'popup', template: templateMethod}", and it popup the editing window, but at the content it just displays "[object] [object]".

Here is my Code:

RouterComponent:

```html
<template>
  <c-main>
  <c-row>
 <c-col xs="24" sm="8">
  <c-panel title="Departamento<small>Workflow</small>" style="height:350px;">
   <div class="u-mt-10"><strong>Nombre</strong></div>
   <div class="u-mt-10">{{ $route.params.name }}</div>
   <div class="u-mt-10"><strong>Descripción</strong></div>
   <div class="u-mt-10">{{ $route.params.description }}</div>
  </c-panel>
 </c-col>
 <c-col xs="24" sm="16">
  <c-panel title="Usuarios<small>Administrar</small>" style="height:350px;">
    <kendo-datasource
     ref="usersdatasource"
     :type="'aspnetmvc-ajax'"
     :pageSize="20"
     :server-filtering='true'
     :transport-read-url= "baseServiceUrl+'/api/DepartmentUsers'"
     :transport-read-type="'GET'"
     :transport-read-data-type="'json'"
     :transport-read-data="dataParameters"
     :transport-destroy-url="baseServiceUrl+'/api/DepartmentUsers'"
     :transport-create-url="baseServiceUrl+'/api/DepartmentUsers'"
     :schema-data= "'Data'"
     :schema-total= "'Total'"
     :schema-errors= "'Errors'"
     :schema-model-id="'Id'"
     :schema-model-fields="usersSchemaModelFields"
     ></kendo-datasource>
     <kendo-grid
    id="usersdatagrid"
    :height="'auto'"
          :dataSourceRef="'usersdatasource'"
    :toolbar="[ {name:'create', text: 'Agregar Usuario'}]"
          :groupable='false'
          :sortable='true'
    :filterable='true'
    :selectable='true'
    :editable="{ mode: 'popup', template: popupTemplate }"
          :pageable-refresh='true'
          :pageable-page-sizes='true'
          :pageable-button-count="5"
    >
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="UserName"
          title="Usuario"
    >
        </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column
          field="DisplayName"
          title="Nombre"
    >
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column 
  :width="150"
  :command="[{name:'destroy', text:'Eliminar' }]" title="Acción">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  
      </kendo-grid>
  </c-panel>
 </c-col>
  </c-row>
  <c-row>
 <c-col xs="24">
 <c-panel title="Reglas<small>Departamento</small>" style="height:400px;">
  <kendo-datasource
            ref="rulesdatasource"
            :type="'aspnetmvc-ajax'"
            :pageSize="20"
            :server-filtering='true'
            :transport-read-url= "baseServiceUrl+'/api/Departments'"
   :transport-read-type="'GET'"
   :transport-read-data-type="'json'"
   :transport-update-url="baseServiceUrl+'/api/Departments'"
   :transport-update-type="'PUT'"
   :transport-update-data-type="'json'"
   :transport-destroy-url="baseServiceUrl+'/api/Departments'"
   :transport-create-url="baseServiceUrl+'/api/Departments'"
   :schema-data= "'Data'"
   :schema-total= "'Total'"
   :schema-errors= "'Errors'"
   :schema-model-id="'Id'"
      ></kendo-datasource>
   <kendo-grid
    id="rulesdatagrid"
    :height="'auto'"
          :dataSourceRef="'rulesdatasource'"
    :groupable='false'
          :sortable='true'
    :filterable='true'
    :selectable='true'
          :pageable-refresh='true'
          :pageable-page-sizes='true'
          :pageable-button-count="5"
    >
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="UserName"
          title="Usuario"
    >
        </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column
          field="Nombre"
          title="DisplayName"
    >
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
   </c-panel>
 </c-col>
  </c-row>
  </c-main>
</template>
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import UserTemplateVue from './departmentUserTemplate.vue'
  var UserTemplate = Vue.component(UserTemplateVue.name, UserTemplateVue)

  export default {
  name: "AddUserDepartmentView",
  data() {
  return {
  baseServiceUrl: window.baseServiceUrl,
  dataParameters: {
 department: $route.params.Id,
 roles: "WORKFLOW;WORKFLOWADMIN"
  },
  filterConfiguration: [],
  usersSchemaModelFields: {
  Id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
  DisplayName: { validation: { required: true } },
  UserName: { validation: { required: true } },
  Email: { validation: { required: true } },
  TenantId: { validation: { required: true } },
  IsAdmin: { validation: { required: true } }
 }
  }
  },
  methods: {
  popupTemplate: function(e) {
 return {
  template: UserTemplate,
  templateArgs: e
 }
  }
  }

  };
</script>

<style>

#usersdatagrid{
 height:100% !important;
}

#rulesdatagrid{
 height:100% !important;
}

</style>
```

Template Component:

```html
<template>
    <span>
        <button @click="buttonClick">Click Me</button>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'template1',
        methods: {
            buttonClick: function (e) {
                alert("Button click")
            }
    },
        data () {
        return {
            templateArgs: {}
            }
    }
    }
</script>
```

Please Help me With this.

Thank You a lot

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I stumbled across this while looking for something related, so I thought I'd take a stab at it for future reference.

Two things I would suggest trying here:

1. Make sure that your component has a name specified.
2. Try using: `editable-mode="popup;"` along with `editable-template="popupTemplate"`

That did the trick for me. For whatever reason, it just wasn't happy when I was passing an object into editable.

Hope that helps!